# Reading Serial data starting from the header

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am reading continuous serial data which is being sent as 29 byte array 
  with the first byte which is the header as a value of oxD1.

How can pick the data in the buffer starting from the Header.

This is my code.

```
 int SerialPort::readSerialPortFreedPacket(BYTE *buffer, unsigned int 
 buf_size)
{
DWORD bytesRead;
int timeout = 500;
OVERLAPPED ovread = { 0 };
ovread.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);



if (ovread.hEvent == NULL) {
    // Error creating overlapped event; abort.
    return FALSE;
}



if (!ReadFile( this->handler , (void*)buffer, 29, &bytesRead, &ovread)) {
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
        // Handle error in communications
        std::cout << "Error reading data " << std::endl;
    }
    else {
        DWORD ret = WaitForSingleObject(ovread.hEvent, timeout);

        switch (ret) {
        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        //  HandleASuccessfulRead(buf, bytesRead);
            std::cout << buffer << std::endl;
            break;
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            // Handle timeout

            break;
        case WAIT_FAILED:
            // Handle failure

            break;
        default:
            // what else to handle?
            break;
        }
    }
}
else {
    // read completed immediately
    //HandleASuccessfulRead(buf,bytesRead);

}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Are you in control of how the packet is constructed? Does your packet have an end delimiter, and do you have any sort of checksum?

Comment: yes the checksum is the byte number 28 with  the value of  0x40 - ( unsigned sum of bytes 0 to 27)

Comment: which is the last byte

Comment: Consider simplifying the code first to get it working.  There is no point in using an overlapped read when you immediately wait for it to complete.  So don't bother with it at all.  You can get a timeout with SetCommTimeouts(), don't do this until after you get it reliable.  Next, you must ensure you get *all* the bytes in the response, keep calling ReadFile() and count down with *bytesRead* until you have all 29 of them.  From there is now gets very easy to verify the checksum and lift out the payload from the frame.